# Sort a list according to order defined by another list

Tags: sorting, subset

How can I sort the elements of the list **A** so that they follow the ordering of another (superset) list **B**?  Assume no duplicates.

E.g. **A** might contain [8 2 5 1] and **B** might contain [5 6 9 8 7 4 1 2 3], and so I'd like to sort **A** to become [5 8 1 2]

I'm interested in ways of doing this efficiently and with good runtime complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **B** is a superset of **A**, I'd just dump **A** into a hash-table, scan **B** and create a new list where I insert every element from **B** that is contained in the hash-table. Uses O(a) extra memory and O(b) runtime.

Comment: This is basically David's 2nd option.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas:

(In the time complexities given, *n* is the size of **A** and *m* is the size of **B**. The time complexities are not simplified.)

- For each element in **B**, do a linear search of **A** to see if that element exists in it. If so, swap it with the first element in **A** that hasn't yet been put into position. *Time complexity: O(nm)*
- Same as above, but first put the contents of **A** into an efficient lookup structure to avoid the linear search. *Time complexity: O(n + m) assuming O(1) lookup*
- Sort **B**. Then, for each element in **A**, find its index (which is guaranteed to exist) within **B** using binary search. Record this index in an auxiliary array the same size as **A**. Use that array of indices as input to a comparator that sorts **A**. *Time complexity: O((m log m) + (n log n) + (n log n))*